# How to make 3D object smooth?

Tags: interpolation, computational-geometry, convolution, splines

*This thread considers mathematical methods [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337887/how-to-make-3d-object-smooth) to make the 3D object smooth but this question consider how to achieve the goal of smoothing a 3D object in Mathematica.*

I want to get smoother geometrical objects, some messing up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzHw9.png). Suppose for example a tetrahedron where I would like to make the corners rounded with either convolution or interpolation. I would have to select two control points on different faces and then select one adjusting point -- I could use a NURBS aka spline approximation with a polynomial then aka Mathematica's BezierCurve[...] command. Now I am trying to do a ready command that would do this for me without me traversing different vertices and making sure of selecting right faces for control/adjusting points. Example data about the coordinates with the tetrahedron's faces [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBpQ.png).

**Does Mathematica have some ready function to do Interpolation or Convolution for geometric objects?**

---

I think the by-far-easiest solution is to use Convex hull but it hides some information if you have a lot of details. This is an answer in progress.

**Different methods**

1. [Convex hull of a 3D object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21841/convex-hull-of-a-3d-object)

Comment: Could you post some simple example to play with?

Comment: Here's a simple, but not very good approach: ``<< PolyhedronOperations`; Graphics3D@
 Nest[Truncate[#, .2] &, N@PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "Faces"], 5]``

Comment: Use a `RegionFunction` that includes points within some epsilon>0 of the boundary?