# Convex hull of a 3D object?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

I am trying to find a convex hull command for a `Graphics3D` object. Does it exist in *Mathematica*?

```
egg = Graphics3D[Cuboid /@ Position[DiskMatrix[{12, 10, 8}], 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `ConvexHull` command of the `` "ComputationalGeometry`" `` package does not work on 3D objects:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
ConvexHull[egg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `ConvexHull` doesn't support 3D points (and you incorrectly tried to compute the `ConvexHull` of the `Graphics` object) your code didn't work.

Here is one way to do what I think you want (I left out of the step of the `Cuboids` but if you want that basically just offset your convex hull).

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]

pos = Position[DiskMatrix[{12, 10, 8}], 1];
Graphics3D[Point@pos]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[pos];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do want to compute the `ConvexHull` of your `Graphics3D` object you can extract the points from the `InputForm`. This is fragile and will only work for this simple case.

```
pos = InputForm[egg][[1, 1, All, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you +1, solved. How did you realize this? Cannot understand why mathematica has no ConvexHull3D[...] command.

Comment: The documentation for `ConvexHull` shows the syntax: `ConvexHull[{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}]` no z coordinate implies that its 2D (x,y) only. Searching `ConvexHull` in the documentation doesn't appear to simply direct you to `TetGenLink` unfortunately. I just knew about it.

Comment: I tried to do similar thing but for some reason it plots none, why? http://i.stack.imgur.com/fbthu.png

Comment: Your statement with `Position` doesn't seem to return anything for me. None of the statements are `1` they are `Cuboid[{_,_,_}]`

Comment: @sOrce, The fact that this link is missing is an oversight on my part. I'll add a link such that when one searches for `ConvexHull` that the TetGenLink example is found. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Without using the TetGen package:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
egg = Graphics3D[{Red, Cuboid /@ Position[DiskMatrix[{3, 4, 5}], 1]}];

v = Flatten[Cases[egg, Cuboid[x_]:> Outer[Plus, Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], {x}, 1][[All, 1]], 3], 1];
prism@v_ = Cases[ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[v], _GraphicsComplex, Infinity];


GraphicsRow@{egg, 
            Show[egg, Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Yellow, prism@v}]], 
            Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], Yellow, prism@v}]}
```

[image]

Comment: That does not appear to be a well-formed polyhedron: it has edges passing through each other and faces that overlap.

Comment: @RahulNarain Yes, it seems so. Apparently a bug in `ConvexHull3D[]` . What a shame!

Comment: Well, dealing with degenerate cases like collinear and coplanar vertices is the hardest part to get right in computational geometry algorithms, and this point set has them in spades. That's probably why they kept the function internal...

Answer (score 8):

In Version 10, there is now the built-in `ConvexHullMesh` to do exactly this.

```
pos = Position[DiskMatrix[{12, 10, 8}], 1];
```

To get the 3D convex hull:

```
ConvexHullMesh[pos]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]