# Efficient drawing of convex polyhedron given a set of points

Tags: graphics3d, performance-tuning

I have a set of points in the 3D space and I want to draw the bounding convex polyhedron of those points. A very naïve solution would be to draw a triangle between every three points:

```
Graphics3D[
    {EdgeForm[None], Polygon[Part[pts, #] & /@ Subsets[Range[Length@pts], {3}]]}, 
    Axes -> True]
```

However, this method is very inefficient. It takes a few seconds to be drawn on my laptop and whenever I want to rotate it using the mouse, it doesn't move smoothly.
I know what the issue is: I am drawing too many triangles, many of them are not even visible (since they are placed inside the polyhedron). But how can I fix it?

Here is an example and the set of the points:

[image: Polyhedron]

```
pts={{0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.79176}, {0., 1.79176, 0.}, {1.79176, 0., 
  0.}, {0., 1.79176, 0.}, {0., 0., 1.79176}, {1.79176, 0., 0.}, {0., 
  1.79176, 0.606136}, {0., 0.606136, 1.79176}, {0., 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0., 0.606136, 1.79176}, {1.79176, 0., 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0., 1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 
  0.}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.}, {1.79176, 0., 0.606136}, {0.606136, 
  0., 1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 
  0.}, {1.79176, 0., 0.}, {0., 1.79176, 0.}, {0., 0., 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0., 0.606136}, {0.606136, 0., 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.}, {0., 
  1.79176, 0.606136}, {0., 0.606136, 1.79176}, {0., 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0., 0.606136, 1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 
  0.}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.}, {1.79176, 0., 0.606136}, {0.606136, 
  0., 1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 
  0.}, {1.79176, 0., 0.606136}, {0.606136, 0., 1.79176}, {1.79176, 
  0.606136, 0.}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.}, {1.79176, 0., 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0., 1.79176}, {0., 1.79176, 0.606136}, {0., 
  0.606136, 1.79176}, {0., 1.79176, 0.606136}, {0., 0.606136, 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.374693}, {1.79176, 0.374693, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.374693}, {0.374693, 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0.374693, 1.79176}, {0.374693, 0.606136, 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.374693}, {1.79176, 0.374693, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.374693}, {0.374693, 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0.374693, 1.79176}, {0.374693, 0.606136, 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.374693}, {1.79176, 0.374693, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.374693}, {0.374693, 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0.374693, 1.79176}, {0.374693, 0.606136, 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.374693}, {1.79176, 0.374693, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.374693}, {0.374693, 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0.374693, 1.79176}, {0.374693, 0.606136, 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.374693}, {1.79176, 0.374693, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.374693}, {0.374693, 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0.374693, 1.79176}, {0.374693, 0.606136, 
  1.79176}, {1.79176, 0.606136, 0.374693}, {1.79176, 0.374693, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 1.79176, 0.374693}, {0.374693, 1.79176, 
  0.606136}, {0.606136, 0.374693, 1.79176}, {0.374693, 0.606136, 
  1.79176}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documented (!) `TetGenConvexHull` can compute the convex hull. Then using a `GraphicsComplex` will be efficient:

```
<< TetGenLink`
{coords, incidences} = TetGenConvexHull[pts];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[incidences]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This should certainly be preferred... :)

Comment: @J.M., I just could not resist. :-)

Comment: @ruebenko Is there an easy way to keep only "real" edges and discard the facets triangulations? (not sure if my question is clear enough ... to see what I mean just don't use `EdgeForm[]` in your code)

Comment: To rephrase @bel's query: how does one merge polygons in the output of `TetGenConvexHull[]` if they are supposedly coplanar?

Comment: @J.M. Yours is a stronger (and preferable) request. I only asked about how to "hide" undesired edges.

Comment: Not directly possible. You'd have to compute the surface triangle normals, then check if the neighbouring facets have a close enough normal and select according to some criterion. Consider: `SphericalNonUniformDistribution[num_] := 
 Table[{Cos[#1] Sin[#2], Sin[#1] Sin[#2], Cos[#2]} &[
   Random[Real, {0, 2 Pi}], Random[Real, {0, Pi}]], {num}]`

Comment: I suppose a criterion like `Norm[Cross[normal1, normal2]] <= tol` might work, then...

Comment: Yes, that's a good choice.

Answer (score 6):

The (undocumented!) function `` ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[] `` is up to the task for this particular case:

```
ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[pts, Axes -> None,
                                           Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces -> False]
```

[image: some convex polyhedron]

Comment: I found ``Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces`` failing (i.e. not terminating) with larger point sets in the past. Like here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23024/193

Comment: @bel, yeah, I've encountered that too during the construction of one of my former avatars. I don't know any workaround either. :(