# Draw an arbitrary convex polyhedron without excess diagonals drawn

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I want to draw a set of convex polyhedrons whose vertices are defined by spherical coordinates  on the surface of a unit sphere.

Currently I followed the advice from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21842/651
But it draws diagonals on any tetragonal face. Each face is composed of triangles. Is it possible to accomplish the same but without tetragonal faces diagonaled?

The current code:

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
mapping[{1,0,0}]={0,0,1}
mapping[{1,Pi,0}]={0,0,-1}
mapping:=CoordinateTransformData[{"Spherical"->"Cartesian"},"Mapping"]
verteces[n_]:=Flatten[Table [{1,Pi k/n, i 2Pi/Binomial[n,k]},{k,0,n},{i,0,Binomial[n,k]-1}],1]
Convex[n_]:=TetGenConvexHull[mapping/@ verteces[n]]
pts[n_]:=First[Convex[n]]
surface[n_] :=Last[Convex[n]]
b:=5
Graphics3D[{Yellow,Opacity[.9],GraphicsComplex[pts[b],Polygon[surface[b]]], Black, Line[{{0,0,-1.1},{0,0,1.1}}]}]
```

Comment: Some code to show where you are at would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Yves Klett I copied the code from the linked answer

Comment: @Yves Klett I have added the current code.

Comment: You can do this: take the triangle list `surface[b]`.  Find the edges.  Each edge has two neighbouring triangles.  For each edge, if those two triangles are parallel (the dot product of their normals is 1 to a certain precision), merge them into a tetragon.  Can you try to implement this?

Comment: Quick fix would be to skip edges with: `GraphicsComplex[pts[b], {EdgeForm[None], Polygon[surface[b]]}]`

Comment: Or what Kuba said, that's even better: loop through edges, and do not render those that have parallel adjacent polygons.

Comment: @Kuba I already tried it. Without edges the picture is uncomprehensible where there are many faces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[mapping /@ verteces[5], 
                                           Axes -> None, Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Mapping over n (well, with a trick because it fails with more than three calculations in a row):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

merging with your code:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
mapping[{1, 0, 0}] = {0, 0, 1}
mapping[{1, Pi, 0}] = {0, 0, -1}
mapping := CoordinateTransformData[{"Spherical" -> "Cartesian"}, "Mapping"]
verteces[n_] := Flatten[Table[{1, Pi k/n, i 2 Pi/Binomial[n,k]}, {k,0,n}, {i, 0,Binomial[n,k]-1}], 1]

Graphics3D[{Yellow, Opacity[.9], 
           Sequence @@ ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[mapping /@ verteces[5], 
           Axes -> None, Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces -> False],Black,Line[{{0, 0, -1.1}, {0, 0, 1.1}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Magic again! +1

Comment: While your result is great, I do not know how to implement it. Where should I put this function?

Comment: @Anixx It's using _your_  `mapping` and `verteces` :) just run it after your code

Comment: How to use the result of this function? I tried to insert it in Graphics3D but it does not work

Comment: Oh, I got it how.

Comment: So what hach you did to make a table?

Comment: I did the following: Hull[n_]:=Cases[ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[mapping/@verteces[n],Axes->None,Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces->False],_GraphicsComplex,Infinity] and it works but does not work if I want to make a table of such polyhedra

Comment: @Anixx ComputationalGeometry`Methods`ConvexHull3D[mapping /@ verteces[#], 
   Axes -> None, Graphics`Mesh`FlatFaces -> False] & /@ Range[5, 7]

Comment: @belisarius without range the table draws 3 polyhedra, with this addition only one

Comment: @belisarius I see 3 graphics

Comment: With Table, the fourth graphic gives an error

Comment: Range[5,8] also gives an error

Comment: Okay, this is another question, I think.

Comment: @Anixx Re-read my answer. I wrote **Mapping over n (well, with a trick because it fails with more than three calculations in a row):**

Comment: @belisarius I see, that's why it is an unrelated topic and deserves another question.

Comment: Seems does not work in Mathematica 10.

Comment: @Anixx No way to test it here. Still on v9

Comment: @Anixx Since Version 10, all methods of the `ComputationalGeometry` package are included in the core Mathematica system. See e.g. `ConvexHullMesh` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution using coplanar triangles idea. Given six vertices of two triangles that share an adjacent edge, we use `EigenValues` to estimate the mean-square orthogonal distance of the points from the best fitting plane. In case it turns out to be close to zero we can assume the two triangles under consideration are coplanar with in some tolerance. You will find more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). Once we know this for any two neighboring triangle in the `TetGen` mesh we can form a Quad by joining them.

```
trigToedge[list_] := Partition[list, 2, 1, 1]; 
Quad[current_, {pt_, tri_}] := 
 Block[{trigtopt, threeTigs, connectedTrigs, dist, mat, test,coplanar, edges},
  trigtopt[list_] := Extract[pt, Transpose@{list}];
  threeTigs = Select[tri, Length@Intersection[#, current] == 2 &];
  connectedTrigs = (trigtopt[#] & /@ threeTigs);
  dist = (
      mat = (# - Mean@#) & /@ (Transpose@(trigtopt[current]~Join~#));
      Min@Chop@Eigenvalues[(mat . Transpose@mat)/6]
      ) & /@ connectedTrigs;
  test = Position[dist, 0];
  {coplanar} = If[test != {}, Extract[threeTigs, test], {0}];
  If[Length@coplanar == 3, 
   edges = Cases[
     Tally[Join @@ (trigToedge /@ {current, coplanar}),
        (#1 == Reverse[#2] &)], {a_, 1} -> a];
   DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Sort[edges, First@#2 == Last@#1 &], 
   current]
  ];
```

**Testing:**

```
b = 9;
tri = surface[b];
pt = pts[b];
poly = Quad[#, {pt, tri}] & /@ tri;
Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[pt, Polygon[poly]], Black}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 350]
```

[image]

As expected we have now the quads whenever they occur for odd `b` values. The current implementation is not optimal for very large meshes but the underlying mathematics is interesting!