# how to get $n$ equidistributed points on the unit sphere

Tags: graphics3d, mathematical-optimization, geometry

We can get $n$ equidistributed points in the unit **circle** using `CirclePoints`. But how do you get $n$ equidistributed points on the unit **sphere**(surface of a ball)? The preliminary idea is to suppose that the points are some electric charges with same electric quantity on a sphere. And they have the same effective working area. I think their position is what I want. This is my current solution:

```
point = RandomPoint[Sphere[], 10^6];
Graphics3D[{Sphere[], Blue, PointSize[.02], 
  Point[Union[point,SameTest -> (EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < 0.4 &)]]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: points]

But this solution cannot draw the specified number of points, and the space is not very equidistributed in some places.

Comment: The vertices of the Platonic and Archimedean solids are in a way the most optimal way to place points on a sphere. If the number of points you need is not the same as the vertex count of any of those solids, you might consider looking up spherical codes or spherical designs, or look at [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S1064827595281344)… my point is, this is a math problem and not a *Mathematica* problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *equally spaced*?  (Points on a circle naturally divide the circle into segments, and we can ask that all the segments to be equal; however, points do not divide a sphere.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Such as the points on a soccer.They divide a sphere into *equally spaced*,I think points can divide a sphere(surface of a ball).

Comment: @yode To me it's the lines that divide the soccer ball, not the points.  The points can be connected in many ways, and the distance between any two is not constant; only those connected by a seam are equidistant.  Surely you would not want figures like [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lNW3F.png) contained in the decomposition, even though as measured by the edges, the points are equally spaced?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Suppose the pionts are some electric charges with same electric quantity on a sphere.And they have a same effective working area.I think their position is what I want

Comment: Equally spaced points about a great circle satisfies your criteria.

Comment: @MichaelE2 They have a small probability even zero to stable in a circle but usual distribute to entire sphere with a *equally spaced* layout.Actually like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119352/21532)

Comment: Perhaps the question and your criteria need to be updated? (Something like you want a *stable* configuration that minimizes the potential energy of an inverse-square law, such as that for electron on a sphere. The choice of a specific objective function to minimize, as opposed to elementary geometric criteria or another function, seems an important omission.  Also requiring stability rules out interesting configurations, although I don't know if that means there is always a unique solution up to rotation/reflection.)

Comment: In any event: *equidistributed* would be the more appropriate term than equispaced in this context.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your vocabulary. :) I have edit the post as the context.

Comment: Ifaik the problem is not solved for arbitrary number of points. Electrostatic approach gives some answers, but I don't remember a reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aha~ I suppose this question is created while solving [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119324/how-to-create-this-spikey-in-mathematica). Am I correct @yode :P

So here's an easy solution, simple, elegant, and may I say even quite fast after some optimization?

```
pt = With[{p = 
     Table[{x[i], y[i], z[i]}, {i, 80(*number of charges*)}]}, 
   p /. Last@
     NMinimize[
      Total[1/Norm[Normalize[#1] - Normalize[#2]] & @@@ 
        Subsets[p, {2}]], Flatten[p, 1]]];
Graphics3D[{Opacity@.3, Darker@Green, Sphere[], Opacity@1, 
  PointSize@Large, Darker@Blue, Point@*Normalize /@ pt}]
```

The result is quite good:

[image: result]

the setting of the minimization variable is crucial, or the point will not be on surface. But fortunately, our 'kindergarten physics' taught us that when charges are freely scattering in a sphere, they'll always be on surface evenly! Thus this must be some sort of 'most even' form of scattering as it follows physical laws.

Comment: You got the idea of God. :)

Comment: but i still cannot get the idea of upvoters~ :P

Comment: This is precisely the Thomson problem mentioned by kirma.

Comment: The generated set of vectors have no unit length, so the sphere is not a unit sphere.

Comment: @plasmacel er, please Normalize them

Answer (score 22):

If more ad hoc, inexact approaches are welcome, one way to generate relatively uniform density of points on a sphere is to use Monte Carlo [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) (modified for the spherical case):

```
With[{points = 200, samples = 40000, iterations = 20}, 
  Nest[With[{randoms = Join[#, RandomPoint[Sphere[], samples]]}, 
     Table[Normalize@Mean@Extract[randoms, Position[#, {i}]], {i, points}] &@
      Nearest[# -> Automatic, randoms, 
       DistanceFunction -> (1 - Dot[#1, #2] &)]] &, 
   RandomPoint[Sphere[], points], iterations]] // 
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.999], Red, Point@#}] &
```

> [image]

**EDIT**:

The above can be written in more concise and much more efficient form as:

```
With[{points = 200, samples = 40000, iterations = 20},
  Nest[
   With[{randoms = Join[#, RandomPoint[Sphere[], samples]]},
     Normalize@Mean@randoms[[#]] & /@ 
      Values@PositionIndex@Nearest[#, randoms]] &,
   RandomPoint[Sphere[], points], iterations]] // 
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.999], Red, Point@#}] &
```

Comment: P.S. `Nearest[# -> Range@Length@#, randoms]` is more compactly done as `Nearest[# -> Automatic, randoms]`

Comment: @J.M. I have a strange tendency to miss these `Automatic` variations... I'll improve the answer.

Comment: I like the idea, but when I tried to use it in high dimensions it got quite slow. I ended up with this approach: Repeatedly find the nearest neighbour for each point; orthogonalize by subtracting the shared component; Reapeat. This converges pretty quickly even for 1000 dimensions.

Answer (score 12):

For an approximately even distribution of points on any surface with cylindrical symmetry, we can use the Golden Angle, the same way that the sunflower uses it on the plane.

To place N points on the surface of a sphere, define an axis. Divide the surface into N equal area strips perpendicular to the axis. For k in 0 to N-1, on the kth strip, place a point at an angle of k*ga, in the centre of its width. ga is the golden angle, 1/(phi+1) of a circle, about 137.5 degrees / 2.34 rads.

This construction can be generalised to the surface of any volume of revolution, for instance a vase or turned table leg, by keeping the area of each strip constant.

Obviously what is being done here is that as each strip is equal area, the construction automatically makes each point 'serve' the same amount of space. Use of the 'most irrational fraction' then does a reasonable job of spreading the points round the axis without any long range structure developing.

---

**Edit by J. M.**

As I noted in a comment to this answer, the phyllotactic arrangement of points on a sphere has been [previously featured on the Wolfram Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/). The code there is more general than what is needed here, so I took the liberty to simplify the code a bit for the spherical case, and also used the fact that `GoldenAngle` is now a built-in constant:

```
With[{n = Floor[4 π 100]},
     Graphics3D[{Sphere[Table[{2 Sqrt[(1 - i/n) i/n] Cos[i GoldenAngle], 
                               2 Sqrt[(1 - i/n) i/n] Sin[i GoldenAngle],
                               1 - 2 i/n}, {i, n}], 100/n]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: phyllotactic arrangement of points on a sphere]

The `100` in the expression for `n` controls the point density; increase or decrease as seen fit.

Comment: [This](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/) is a Wolfram Blog entry that discusses the phyllotaxis strategy. Of note: `GoldenAngle` is now built-in.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was a report on the Starshine 3 satellite that first brought this method to my attention, needless to say I couldn't google up the name when I wanted it!

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd like to edit your post later to include some of the code from that link, just to make your post even more prominent (this is a site that expects some amount of code, after all).

Comment: Go for it, I'm all for cooperation. I was surprised to see no mention of phyllotaxis so far in this thread, hence the text-only post from a non-Mathematica user (I'm a python+matplotlib+numpy man). Even given your link I was reluctant to transplant code as I'm not in a position to verify it. I was surprised to see phyllotaxis used for Starshine, as I can't imagine a hard constraint on N. I built a LED sphere recently, and triangular tiled the faces of an icoshedron, a straightforward construction, mathematically, mechanically and electrically.

Answer (score 10):

Correct me if I'm wrong... but I suppose, pedantically speaking, there are only five solutions defined by Platonic solids, and trivial solutions for 0-3 points (extension of `CirclePoints`).

Thus:

```
ClearAll[spherePoints];

spherePoints[r_: 1, n_ /; 0 <= n < 4] := {##, 0} & @@@ CirclePoints[r, n];

(spherePoints[r_: 1, PolyhedronData[#, "VertexCount"]] := 
     r (Normalize /@ PolyhedronData[#, "VertexCoordinates"])) & /@ 
  PolyhedronData["Platonic"];
```

Now:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[spherePoints[12]], 
  Opacity[1/2], White, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.99]}]
```

> [image]

For non-Platonic configurations, function stays unevaluated:

```
spherePoints[5]
```

> spherePoints[5]

Tammes and Thomson problems can be considered as an extension for non-Platonic cases. For instance, see Math Overflow: [Distributing points evenly on a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212550/distributing-points-evenly-on-a-sphere). Sadly, general solutions to these problems are not trivial.

Comment: If I put `n` electric charges in the sphere,we will get the stable layout?Then we can get the layout.

Comment: @yode I think Thompson problem is exactly that. Solving this using numerical optimization on Mma is not that hard, but I don't know how close to optimal solutions achieved this way actually are.

Comment: @yode The following numerically solves the Thomson problem for a ten-point case: `With[{points = Array[c, {10, 3}]}, points /. Last@NMinimize[Total[1 / EuclideanDistance @@ # & /@ Subsets[points, {2}]], # \[Element] Sphere[] & /@ points]]`. It is not really very fast, but it's reasonably simple...

Comment: And the same for Tammes problem: `With[{points = Array[c, {10, 3}]}, points /. Last@NMaximize[Min[EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[points, {2}]], # \[Element] Sphere[] & /@ points]]`.

Comment: The evaluation can be eased a bit by fixing one of the points to be a "standard" point, such as any of the unit basis vectors, and constraining a second point to lie on a coordinate plane containing the fixed point set earlier.

Answer (score 10):

```
With[{n = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20}},
  Partition[show[points[#]] & /@ n, 3]] // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

With the code below, with piecewise spring forces (exclusively repulsive) and Cartesian vectors. A different model for force and switch to spherical vectors would probably be wise.

```
show[points_] :=
 Graphics3D[{
   Opacity[.5], Sphere[],
   Opacity[1], PointSize[Medium], Point[points]},
  ImageSize -> Tiny,
  Boxed -> False]

points[n_] :=
 With[{
   steps = 50,
   start = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n]},
  Nest[move[#, .1] &, start, steps]]

move[points_, dt_] :=
 With[{n = Length[points]},
  Module[{copy = points},
   Do[
    copy[[i]] += dt Sum[force[copy[[j]], copy[[i]]],
       {j, DeleteCases[Range[n], i]}];
    copy[[i]] = copy[[i]]/Norm[copy[[i]]],
    {i, n}];
   copy]]

force[p1_, p2_] :=
 With[{d = VectorAngle[p1, p2], range = Pi},
  If[d > range, 0, Normalize[p2 - p1]*(range - d)]]
```

### Update: Simulated Annealing

Start with n random points on the unit sphere. Then do the main loop: pick a point randomly and make a random move. If the move lowers the energy (electro-static potential), accept the move into a new configuration. Accept the move also, this is crucial, if the energy difference is less then `Exp[-difference/T]`, where `T` is a temperature-like control parameter. Do `K1 * Length[points]` of these inner iterations (about 10, so each point is picked about ten times) and `K2` outer passes of the inner iterating. Before each outer pass `T` is set, i.e. gradually lowered from some starting value (few times higher than a typical temperature change) to zero.

Results agree with literature on this, so-called Thomson problem.

```
start = points[18];
result = Reap[simulation[start, 10, 10]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.7106, Null} *)
```

Energy is recorded in the main loop:

```
ListPlot[result[[2, 1]],
 Joined -> True,
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Table[Graphics3D[{
    PointSize[Medium], Point[xyz /@ p],
    Opacity[.75], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .99]},
   ImageSize -> Small,
   Boxed -> False,
   SphericalRegion -> True],
  {p, {start, result[[1]]}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Code:

```
points[n_Integer] :=
 With[{x := RandomReal[]},
  Table[{2 Pi \[Xi], ArcCos[2 \[Xi] - 1]}, n]]

xyz[{u_, v_}] :=
 {Sin[v] Cos[u], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[v]}

energy[points_] :=
 With[{n = Length[points]},
  Sum[1/EuclideanDistance @@ (xyz /@ points[[{i, j}]]),
   {i, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]]

(* O(n) instead of energy O(n^2) *)
dE[points_, i_, r_] :=
 With[{n = Length[points]},
  Module[{indices, before, after},
   indices = DeleteCases[Range[n], i];
   before = Sum[
     1/Norm[xyz@points[[j]] - xyz@points[[i]]], {j, indices}];
   after = Sum[
     1/Norm[xyz@points[[j]] - xyz@r], {j, indices}];
   after - before]]

simulation[start_, K1_, K2_] :=
 With[{
   n = Length[start],
   du = .1 Pi,
   dv = .1 Pi,
   x := RandomReal[]},
  Module[{T, temp = start},
   Do[
    T = 10 (1 - (k1 - 1)/K1)^5;
    temp = Nest[
      Module[{i, p, change},
        (* monitor energy; must Reap *)
        Sow[energy[#]];
        i = RandomInteger[{1, n}];
        p = #[[i]] + {du (2 x - 1), dv (2 x - 1)};
        change = dE[#, i, p];
        If[change < 0 || (x < Exp[-change/T]),
         ReplacePart[#, i -> p], #]] &, temp, K2 n], {k1, K1}];
   temp]]
```

Comment: Upvote.But it seem the points not very equidistributed such as this [angle of view](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-06-26-00-59-42.png) in some place.If you have fixed this,I think I should accept this answer in consideration of the code efficiency

Comment: @yode One can tweak the `steps`, `force` etc., and see what works best. I remembered another approach which lends to this problem, see update.

Answer (score 8):

Mathematica 11.1 has a built-in function for this task: `SpherePoints`. This roughly corresponds `CirclePoints` for three-dimensional case; thus I wouldn't rely on it to get any sort of randomness on the point placement.

**EDIT**: An implementation with `SpherePoints`, with an added random rotation:

```
Outer[Dot, SpherePoints[200], 
  RandomVariate@CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3], 1] // 
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.999], Red, Point@#}] &
```

[image]

This works with larger number of points (10000), too:

[image]

Comment: I think the Wolfram Research guys have seen this question,then go home to build a `SpherePoints`. :)

Comment: And If you want to get a random point,you just rotate a random angle around the centre of sphere

Comment: @yode Ah, now I understand your point. Indeed, although set of more or less equidistant points on a sphere are not absolutely random, you can improve the situation by choosing a random direction (random point on a sphere once again), and perform an uniformly distributed random rotation around it. You can alternatively pick a variate from `CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]` which provides uniform samples from random 3D rotation matrices - which you can use to rotate the point set.

Comment: Yes,that is what I mean. :)

Answer (score 2):

For points uniformly spaced in angular variables, you can use `CirclePoints`.

```
spherepoint[m_, n_] := Union@Flatten[Table[Join[{Cos[q]}, 
                        Sin[q] #] & /@ CirclePoints[n], {q, 0, Pi, Pi/m}], 1]

ListPointPlot3D[spherepoint[20, 30], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

For uniformly spaced in Cartesian coordinates, things would be complicated. The best I can suggest is to go for scaled `PolyhedronData` and try to map them on the sphere. You can find your polyhedron for any given number of face (or vertices, there is a relation I forgot). For example

```
pts = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCount"]
PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "FaceCount"]
r = Norm[pts[[1]]];
Show[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"], 
SphericalPlot3D[r, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]
```

> 20
>
> 12

[image]

You have to scale the data with `r` to bring them on unit circle.

You might find this interesting for any arbitrary polygon

[Draw an arbitrary convex polyhedron without excess diagonals drawn](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37835/draw-an-arbitrary-convex-polyhedron-without-excess-diagonals-drawn)

Comment: It's seem the spaced isn't equal each other?

Comment: They are uniformly spaced in angular variable. Are you looking for uniform spacing in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Yes,uniform spacing in cartesian coordinates.Can you help me update your solution?

Comment: "for any given number of face (or vertices, there is a relation I forgot)." - you might want to look up dual polyhedra. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I posted an implementation of the spherical Lloyd algorithm in [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1302146). Applied to this problem, we have the following:

```
n = 50; (* number of points *)
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1337, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
            sp = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, 3}]];

With[{maxit = 45,(* maximum iterations *)
      tol = 0.001 (* distance tolerance *)}, 
     lp = FixedPoint[Function[pts, 
                     Block[{ch, polys, verts, vor},
                           ch = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
                           verts = MeshCoordinates[ch];
                           polys = First /@ MeshCells[ch, 2];
                           vor = Normalize[Cross[verts[[#2]] - verts[[#1]], 
                                                 verts[[#3]] - verts[[#1]]]] &
                                 @@@ polys;
                           SphericalPolygonCentroid[vor[[#]]] & /@ 
                           ch["VertexFaceConnectivity"]]], sp, maxit, 
                     SameTest -> (Max[MapThread[cosDistance, {#1, #2}]] < tol &)]];

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.75], Sphere[]}, {Green, Sphere[lp, 0.02]}}, 
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: sphere points after Lloyd relaxation]

---

To keep this answer self contained, here are the required auxiliary routines:

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97854 *)
vecang[v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ] := Module[{n1 = Norm[v1], n2 = Norm[v2]},
       2 ArcTan[Norm[v1 n2 + n1 v2], Norm[v1 n2 - n1 v2]]]

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167114 *)
vectorRotate[vv1_?VectorQ, vv2_?VectorQ] := 
 Module[{v1 = Normalize[vv1], v2 = Normalize[vv2], c, d, d1, d2, t1, t2},
        d = v1.v2;
        If[TrueQ[Chop[1 + d] == 0],
           c = UnitVector[3, First[Ordering[Abs[v1], 1]]];
           t1 = c - v1; t2 = c - v2; d1 = t1.t1; d2 = t2.t2;
           IdentityMatrix[3] - 2 (Outer[Times, t2, t2]/d2 - 
           2 t2.t1 Outer[Times, t2, t1]/(d2 d1) + Outer[Times, t1, t1]/d1),

           c = Cross[v1, v2];
           d IdentityMatrix[3] + Outer[Times, c, c]/(1 + d) - LeviCivitaTensor[3].c]]

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154112 *)
sphereExp[q_?VectorQ, p_?VectorQ] /; Length[q] == Length[p] + 1 := 
      With[{n = Norm[p]}, vectorRotate[{0, 0, 1}, q].Append[p Sinc[n], Cos[n]]]

sphereLog[q_?VectorQ, p_?VectorQ] /; Length[q] == Length[p] := 
      Most[vectorRotate[q, {0, 0, 1}].p]/Sinc[vecang[p, q]]

SphericalPolygonCentroid[pts_?MatrixQ] := Module[{k = 0, n = Length[pts], cp, h, pr},
         cp = Normalize[Total[pts]];
         pr = Internal`EffectivePrecision[pts];
         While[cp = sphereExp[cp, h = Sum[sphereLog[cp, p], {p, pts}]/n];
               k++; Norm[h] > 10^(-pr/2) && k <= 30];
         cp]

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159465 *)
cosDistance[v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ] := 
   Module[{n1 = Normalize[v1], n2 = Normalize[v2], y},
          y = Norm[n1 - n2]^2; 2 y/(Norm[n1 + n2]^2 + y)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course,we have `SpherePoints` in `11.1`,but if we are in before version,we can use `IGLayoutSphere` to do it,which is in a package [IGraphM](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) writed by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs).As its doucument

> `IGLayoutSphere[graph]` lays out vertices approximately uniformly distributed on a sphere.

It's exactly what I want.

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]    
g = IGLayoutSphere[CompleteGraph[50]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Point[GraphEmbedding[g]], Sphere[]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regular equidistribution can be achieved by choosing circles of latitude at constant intervals $dθ$ and on these circles points with distance $dφ $, such that $dθ \approx dφ$ and that $dθdφ$ equals the average area per point. This then gives the following algorithm:

***(In short, the basic idea is to divide the surface area into small squares (each square effectively contains one point), then find the theta, phi. Convert them into Cartesian coordinates)***

```
lst = {};
num = 100 (*  close to required number of points*);
r = 1.;
(*Discretise theta and phi*)
ar = (4.*Pi*r^2)/num; 
len = Sqrt[ar]; ndthe = Round[Pi/len]; len2 = ar/len;
For[m = 0, m <= ndthe - 1, m = m + 1,
theta = (m + 1/2)*(Pi/ndthe);
nphi = Round[2*Pi*Sin[theta]/len2];
For[n = 0, n <= nphi - 1, n = n + 1,
phi = (n)*(2*Pi/nphi);
(* spherical to cart *)
x = r*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi];
y = r*Sin[theta]*Sin[phi];
z = r*Cos[theta];
cor = {x, y, z};
corr = AppendTo[lst, cor]]]
ListPointPlot3D[corr, BoxRatios -> 1]
ListPlot3D[{corr, -corr}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]
[image]

[Ref-Short Discription](https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/sphere_equi.pdf)

[Ref-Detailed Discription](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3223966/)

More precisely, These points are orthogonally equidistant.

Comment: You really don't need to use `For[]`: `Block[{r, num, ar, len, ndthe, theta, nphi, phi},
 r = 1.; num = 100; ar = (4 Pi r^2)/num; len = Sqrt[ar]; ndthe = Round[Pi/len]; Flatten[Table[theta = (m + 1/2) (Pi/ndthe); nphi = Round[2 Pi Sin[theta]/len]; Table[phi = 2 Pi n/nphi; r {Sin[theta] Cos[phi], Sin[theta] Sin[phi], Cos[theta]}, {n, 0, nphi - 1}], {m, 0, ndthe - 1}], 1]]`

Comment: @J.M., Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Marsaglia's method: uniform on disk (here rejection method), transform by Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

```
uniformDisk[n_] := 
  Take[Select[Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {3 n}, {2}], #.# <= 1 &], n];

diskToSphere[p_] := {2 p[[1]] Sqrt[1 - Dot[p, p]], 
                     2 p[[2]] Sqrt[1 - Dot[p, p]],
                     1 - 2 Dot[p, p]}

Graphics3D[{
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .999],
  Specularity[Blue, 10],
  Sphere[Map[diskToSphere, uniformDisk[1256]], .015]},
  Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: This is more of an answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038), but Marsaglia's method is already there.

Comment: Didn't see it.  Rereading does the OP mean "well-spaced" then and not " equidistributed"... like some low discrepancy on $\mathbb{S}^2$?

Comment: I would say that the more appropriate term is "uniformly distributed" if you are talking about (quasi)-randomly generated points.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case what you were *really* asking was how to distribute $n$ points relatively evenly on an $d$-dimensional hypersphere, here's a code snippet that will work... :)

```
    genSphere[n_, d_] :=
      Table[
        Normalize[
          RandomVariate[
            MultinormalDistribution[
              ConstantArray[0, d],IdentityMatrix[d]
            ]
          ]
        ], {n}]
```

Comment: How to understand [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pEaSn.png)?

Comment: Oops, had to take out the "Abs[ ]", which was putting all points in the positive quadrant. Use this to generate data to test multi-dimensional geometric algorithms.

Comment: Thanks,and do you test `Graphics3D[{Point[genSphere[20, 3]], Sphere[]}]`?It's not a good [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0KYDy.png) still.

Comment: The points are distributed as per a uniform distribution over the surface (each patch has same probability of getting a point as any other patch of the same size) but that inevitably results in a clumpy appearance. This could be a good seed for the simulated annealing or other iterative algorithm. It also readily generalizes to arbitrary dimension, which I find fascinating, based on its simplicity.

Comment: This is more of an answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038).

Comment: Is there a reference for the argument behind the geosphere[n_,d_] function?

Comment: Should this produce a "superior" (lower-discrepancy) sequence of points than that in the mathworld entry http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html  ?

Comment: Paul, it is based on the well-known principle that for a multi-dimensional normal distribution with zero mean vector and $\Sigma$ equal to the identity matrix, the probability of a point is independent of direction. You can use this reference...Generating Data for Testing Pareto Sorting Algorithms, Conference Paper · September 2006, DOI: 10.2514/6.2006-6981,  https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2006-6981

Comment: I don't think it will product a lower discrepency distribution (ala quasi-monte carlo).