# Transform sphere to an ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra, geometry

In Lay's Linear Algebra and Its Applications textbook, he defines the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 11 & 14\\8 & 7 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$
and claims that the transformation $T(x)=A x$ maps the sphere to an ellipse.

[image]

I'm still struggling with the mathematics on why this is true, but I would like to be able to come up with a way in Mathematica to demonstrate the transformation of the unit sphere to this ellipse to my students.

**Update:** There is some wonderful support on this page. Thanks to all, but I'd also like to see if it is possible to use Mathematica to produce the equation of the ellipse that is the border of the region.

Answer (score 23):

Another visualization you might find helpful:

```
sp = MeshCoordinates[
   DiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.02]];
el = Map[(A.#)~Join~{-10} &, sp];
```

I used [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) and [`MeshCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCoordinates.html) to get the points.  From here I apply the mapping, but add a "z" coordinate for display purposes so you can see where each point on the sphere gets mapped to on the ellipse.

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5, Blue], Sphere[], Arrowheads[0.02], 
   MapThread[Arrow[{##}] &, {sp, el}] }], ListPlot3D[el], 
 ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 21):

```
x = Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ];
y = Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ];
z = Cos[θ];
A = {{4, 11, 14}, {8, 7, -2}};
ParametricPlot[
 A.{x, y, z}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ColorFunction -> "MintColors"]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice: shows what happens to the latitudes and longitudes, facilitating OP's interpretation of the actual transformation.

Comment: @yarchik Is all the code present here for drawing this image? I am using Mathematica 11 and I'm not getting all of those mesh lines.

Comment: @David, yes, I have MA9

Comment: On Mathematica 10 I get the lines only after I add `Mesh -> 20` to the `ParametricPlot`. @David

Comment: I'd like to thank all of my colleagues for all of their wonderful assistance. This page has some absolutely wonderful answers.

Answer (score 14):

Generating equidistributed points on a sphere [according to this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119341/22013):

```
pts = With[{points = 200, samples = 40000, iterations = 20}, 
   Nest[With[{randoms = Join[#, RandomPoint[Sphere[], samples]]}, 
      Normalize @ Mean @ randoms[[#]] & /@ 
       Values @ PositionIndex @ Nearest[#, randoms]] &, 
    RandomPoint[Sphere[], points], iterations]];

ListPointPlot3D[#, BoxRatios -> 1]& @ pts
```

[image]

```
A = {{4, 11, 14}, {8, 7, -2}};

ellipse = Dot[A, #]& /@ pts;
(* which is the same as pts.Transpose[A] *)

ell = ListPlot[ellipse, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

The points on a unit sphere above are equidistributed. To make a uniform random distribution of points one needs to generate the spherical angles $b$ and $l$ [according to](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html)

$$b=\arccos(2u-1)$$
$$l=2\pi v$$

where $u,v$ are $\mathcal{U}[0,1)$ iid:

```
ang = Table[{ArcCos[2 RandomReal[] - 1], 2 \[Pi] RandomReal[]}, {i, 1000}];
```

Then transform it to Cartesian coordinates $(x,y,z)$:

```
sph = {Sin[#1] Cos[#2], Sin[#1] Sin[#2], Cos[#1]}& @@@ ang;
ListPointPlot3D[#, BoxRatios -> 1]& @ sph
```

[image]

(*EDIT: As [Michael E2 pointed out in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/transform-sphere-to-an-ellipse-in-r2/127647?noredirect=1#comment345414_127647), `sph` can be obtained with a built-in function: `sph = RandomPoint[Sphere[], 1000]`.*)

```
ellipse = Dot[A, #]& /@ sph;
pl2 = RegionPlot[ConvexHullMesh[ellipse], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Thanks to [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/transform-sphere-to-an-ellipse-in-r2#comment345221_127647) for pointing out the `RegionPlot`.

Comment: `RegionPlot[ConvexHullMesh[ellipse], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`

Comment: You could also use `Show[ConvexHullMesh[ellipse], Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`

Comment: Note that in V10 we got `RandomPoint[]`, so one may use `pts = RandomPoint[Sphere[], 200]`. Also note `ellipse == pts.Transpose[A]`.

Answer (score 14):

**Visualization**

From a `GeometricTransformation` on the unit sphere:

```
unitsphere = Sphere[];
transformTo2D = {{4, 11, 14}, {8, 7, -2}};
transformIn3D = Append[transformTo2D, {0, 0, 0}];

g = Graphics3D[
  {Black, GeometricTransformation[unitsphere, transformIn3D]}, 
  Boxed -> False
]
```

[image]

We can visualize the resulting ellipse together with the initial sphere with:

```
Graphics3D[
   {Red, unitsphere, Opacity[0.5], Black, 
    GeometricTransformation[unitsphere, transformIn3D]
   }, Boxed -> False
]
```

[image]

**Equation of the ellipse**

> I'd also like to see if it is possible to use *Mathematica* to produce the equation of the ellipse that is the border of the region.

*Parameters of the ellipse.*

With `mat` the transformation matrix and `p` a point on the sphere,

```
mat = {{4, 11, 14}, {8, 7, -2}};
p = {x, y, z};
```

the length `a` of the semi-major axis of the ellipse and the coordinates of one of the corresponding points on the boundary are given by:

```
solmaj = Maximize[{Norm[mat.p], y >= 0}, Element[p, Sphere[]]]
(* {6 Sqrt[10], {x -> 1/3, y -> 2/3, z -> 2/3}} *)

a = solmaj [[1]]
(* 6 Sqrt[10] *)

pmaj = mat.solmaj [[2, All, 2]]
(* {18, 6} *)
```

Similarly, the length `b` of the semi-minor axis and the coordinates of one of the corresponding points are given by:

```
solmin = Maximize[{Norm[mat.p], Projection[mat.p, pmaj] == 0}, Element[p, Sphere[]]]
(* {3 Sqrt[10], {x -> -(2/3), y -> -(1/3), z -> 2/3}} *)

b = solmin[[1]]
(* 3 Sqrt[10] *)

pmin = mat.solmin[[2, All, 2]]
(* {3, -9} *)
```

The angle between the semi-major axis and the $x$-axis is:

```
α = VectorAngle[pmaj, {1, 0}]
(* ArcCos[3/Sqrt[10]] *)
```

*Equations.*

From the above definitions, we can plot the ellipse with the parametric equation:

```
ParametricPlot[
   {a Cos[t] Cos[α] - b Sin[t] Sin[α], 
    a Cos[t] Sin[α] + b Sin[t] Cos[α]
   }, {t, 0, 2 π},
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], DotDashed,
     Red, Point[{pmaj, -pmaj}], Line[{pmaj, -pmaj}], 
     Brown, Point[{pmin, -pmin}], Line[{pmin, -pmin}]
   }
]
```

[image]

and write the canonical form of the equation

$$ \left(\frac{x \cos{\alpha} + y \sin{\alpha}}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x \sin{\alpha} - y \cos{\alpha}}{b}\right)^2 = 1 $$

as

```
((x Cos[α] + y Sin[α])/ a)^2 + ((x Sin[α] - y Cos[α])/b)^2 // Simplify
```

$$ \frac{13 x^2 - 18 x y + 37 y^2}{3600} = 1 $$

Comment: May I ask how you got the canonical form?

Comment: @David See update.

Comment: This will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This is going to be a tremendous learning experience. Great answer!

Comment: @David Glad this was helpful. This was a nice question with many interesting answers!

Answer (score 14):

Another way:

```
mat = {{4, 11, 14}, {8, 7, -2}};
sph[{x_, y_, z_}] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;

ContourPlot[sph[PseudoInverse[mat].{u, v}] == 1,
 {u, -20, 20}, {v, -20, 20},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large, Point[{{18, 6}, {3, -9}}], 
   Line[{{{18, 6}, -{18, 6}}, {{3, -9}, -{3, -9}}}]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Simplify[sph[PseudoInverse[mat].{u, v}] == 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(If a set of points $\{p\}$ satisfies $F(p)=0$, then the transformed set $\{q=T(p)\}$ satisfies $F(T^{-1}(q))=0$.)

---

Aside: You can get the semi-major axes of the transformed ellipse from [`SingularValueDecomposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingularValueDecomposition.html).

```
{U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat];

U.Σ // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The zero vector could be interpreted as one of the axes of the sphere collapsing under the transformation.

The axes of the sphere represented by the third component `v` are mapped to the above by the transformation:

```
mat.V // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some referencess:

[David Austin, "We Recommend a Singular Value Decomposition", *Feature Column*, AMS (undated?, online)](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-svd)

[D. Kalman, "A singularly valuable decomposition: The svd of a matrix", *The College Mathematics
Journal* **27** (1996), no. 1, 2-23; revised 2002](http://www.math.umn.edu/~lerman/math5467/svd.pdf)

---

More on the SVD:

If $(x,y)$ denotes the inner product, then
$$\|Ax\|^2=(Ax,Ax)=(x,A^TAx) \le \lambda \cdot(x,x) = \lambda\,,$$
where $\lambda$ is the greatest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, which has nonnegative real eigenvalues.  Consequently $\sqrt{\lambda}$ is the greatest singular value of $A$ and the maximum of $\|Ax\|$, which is achieved when $x$ is a unit eigenvector of $A^TA$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

---

SVD Demo:
An ${\bf R}^3 \rightarrow {\bf R}^2$ version of the illustration in the Austin article (ref. above).

Note that in the SVD below, `V` is an orthogonal matrix and represents a rigid motion that aligns the standard coordinate vectors with the eigenvectors of $A^TA$. In this case it is a reflection and `-V` is a rotation that accomplishes the same alignment.  The demo allows the user to rotate the unit sphere from the pole aligned with the z-axis to a sphere with a pole aligned with the eigenvector corresponding to the singular value $0$. In fact, it may be rotated so that the pole may aligned with any of the three eigenvectors.

```
{U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat]; (* from above *)
rot[θ_] = RotationMatrix[θ, First@Pick[##, 1] & @@ Reverse@Eigensystem[-V]];

axesplot[
   xform_,          (* transformation =  mat  or  IdentityMatrix[3]  *)
   angle_           (* rotation angle for  rot[]  *)
   ] := With[{
    axes = Transpose[rot[angle]], 
    colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[{1, 3, 4}]]},
   {Red, PointSize@Large, Thick,
    MapThread[                         (* rotated axes *)
     Function[{axis, color}, {color, Point[axis], Line[{-axis, axis}]}],
     {Transpose[xform.axes], colors}],
    Gray, Thickness[Medium],           (* axes transformed by V *)
    InfiniteLine[{{0, 0, 0}, #}.Transpose[xform]] & /@ Transpose[V]}
   ];
sphParam[θ_, ϕ_] = CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {1, ϕ, θ}];

Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{
   (* sphere *)
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[rot[t].sphParam[θ, ϕ],
     {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, {ϕ, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 15],
    Graphics3D[axesplot[IdentityMatrix[3], -t]],
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Ticks -> None, 
    ViewPoint -> Dynamic@vp, ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vv, (* preserves view as t changes *)
    SphericalRegion -> True
    ],
   (* mat.sphere *)
   ParametricPlot[mat.rot[t].sphParam[θ, ϕ],
    {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, {ϕ, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> None, 
    Mesh -> 15, BoundaryStyle -> {Gray, Thin}, 
    Epilog -> axesplot[mat, -t], Axes -> None
    ]
   }],
 {t, 0., 2. Pi, TrackingFunction ->  (* sets "stops" at critical angles *)
   (t = Nearest[Pi Range[1, 5, 2]/3, #, {1, 0.07}] /. {{} -> #, {tt_} :> tt}; &),
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 (* ViewPoint, ViewVertical variables, without controls *)
 {{vp, {1.3, -2.4, 2}}, None}, {{vv, {0, 0, 1}}, None}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Aligned with the eigenvectors:

[image]
[image]
[image]