# Transformation of Unit Circle to a Plane in $R^3$

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra

I have matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\1 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
The question, similar to the discussion at [Transform sphere to an ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/transform-sphere-to-an-ellipse-in-mathbbr2), is to find the parametric equation of the transformation of the unit circle with $T(x)=Ax$.

I showed that the transformation maps $R^2$ to a plane in $R^3$. The plane will be the column space of matrix $A$. Because the null space of the $A^T$ is the orthogonal complement of the column space of matrix $A$, I can do this:

```
A = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
NullSpace[Transpose[A]]
```

Which gives this basis for the null space of $A^T$.
$$\beta=\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\1\\1
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Now I can do this:

```
Clear[x, y, z]
{x, y, z}.First[NullSpace[Transpose[A]]]
```

Which gives me the equation of the plane as $-x+y+z=0$. Solving for $z$ gives me $z=x-y$, so I can draw this transformation of $R^2$.

```
Plot3D[x - y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Next, I selected 100 random points from the unit circle (corey979's cool idea), then applied $T(x)=Ax$ to the set of points, using Michael E2's cool move.

```
pts = RandomPoint[Circle[], 100];
tpts = pts.Transpose[A];
```

Then I added these points to my image.

Show[

```
 Plot3D[x - y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, PointSize[Large],
   Point[tpts]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

So I have excellent visualization that the transformation maps the unit circle to an ellipse on the plane $-x+y+z=0$ in $R^3$.

But, now my question. How can I find a parametric equation representing this ellipse in the plane so I can use ParametricPlot3D to graph it?

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer to the [question you refered to](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/transform-sphere-to-an-ellipse-in-mathbbr2)? They are all excellent, so the choice might be hard, but I'm sure it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Just transform your favourite parametrization of the cirle,e.g.:

```
mat = {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Show[
 Plot3D[x - y, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[mat.{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}
  ], Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[mat.# & /@ RandomPoint[Circle[], 10]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks so much for the help.