# How can you calculate a volume from a closed countour from ListContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, data, geometry

I have a set of data from which I'm able to generate closed contours (surfaces) in with ListContourPlot3D. I would like to determine the (approximate) volume of these surfaces as well as their surface areas. Is this possible in some manner?

Comment: Where is the data?

Comment: This is highly dependant on the surface.   Oftentimes the output from `ContourPlot3D` includes many polygons with 4 points which aren't quite as planar as the region functions want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DelaunayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html), [`RegionBoundary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBoundary.html), and [`RegionMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html)

Points on a unit sphere for example data
(Taken from:[how to get $n$ equidistributed points on the unit sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119329/how-to-get-n-equidistributed-points-on-the-unit-sphere/119461)):

```
points = With[{points = 5000, samples = 40000, iterations = 20}, 
   Nest[With[{randoms = Join[#, RandomPoint[Sphere[], samples]]}, 
      Normalize@Mean@randoms[[#]] & /@ 
       Values@PositionIndex@Nearest[#, randoms]] &, 
    RandomPoint[Sphere[], points], iterations]];
```

Calculating volume and surface area:

```
ListContourPlot3D[points, Contours -> {0}]
object = DelaunayMesh[points];
objectSurface = RegionBoundary[object];

RegionMeasure[object, 3]
RegionMeasure[objectSurface, 2]
```

> 4.18349
>
> 12.5579

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html) to convert the contour plot to a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, then measure the volume and surface area of the region.

```
data = Table[x^4 + y^4 + z^4, {x, -1, 1, 0.2}, {y, -1, 1, 0.2}, {z, -1, 1, 0.2}];

g = ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> {0.8}, 
  DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
b = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[g]
```

[image]

```
RegionMeasure /@ {b, RegionBoundary[b]}
(* {5.2023, 15.2752} *)
```

Comment: Should this work in V10.4?

Comment: @Young, I'm not sure - I'm using version 11.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me on 10.4.1