# Equal point charges on the sphere

Tags: physics, simulation

I have coded a simulation where **$n$ equal charges** are randomly placed **on** the surface of the conducting **sphere**. I added a damping term proportional to velocity so that the charges arrange in a stable configuration. Then the graphics of polyhedron with charges as vertices is displayed.

[image]

It **works for** every number of charges **less than 78**. It takes my computer around 20 seconds for 77 but for **78 or greater it just freezes**.

Below is the code. Under each defined function there is a description of what it does

Is there a way to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

```
NaključnaTNaKrogli[r_: 1] := {
    {x, y, z} = {RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
      RandomReal[{-1, 1}]};
    If[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1,
     r {x, y, z}/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2],
     NaključnaTNaKrogli[r]]
    }[[1]];
(*returns random point on the sphere of radius r, centered at {0,0,0}*)


l[vektor_] := Sqrt[vektor.vektor]; 
(*returns magnitude(length) of a vector*)
L[sez_] := l /@ sez;
Strešca[vektor_] := vektor/l[vektor];
STREŠCA[sez_] := sez/L[sez];
sez\[CapitalDelta]r[sezr_, n_, i_] := 
  ConstantArray[sezr[[i]], n - 1] - Delete[sezr, i];
(*returns list of vectors from i'th charge to all other charges in \
sezr. n=Length[sezr]*)
F[sezr_, n_, i_, c_] := {
    s = sez\[CapitalDelta]r[sezr, n, i];
    c Total[s/L[s]^3]
    }[[1]];
(*returns list of force vectors of other charges on i'th charge in \
sezr. c is  q^2/(4Subscript[\[Pi]\[Epsilon], 0])*)
Seza[sezr_, n_, c_, m_, k_, sezV_] := {
    rstre = STREŠCA[sezr];
    sezF = 
     Reap[                                                          
        Do[
         Sow[
          F[sezr, n, j, c]
          ]
         , {j, n}]
        ][[2]][[1]];
    
    (sezF - rstre (Total /@ (rstre sezF)) - k sezV)/m
    }[[1]];

(*returns list of acceloration vectors of charges. sezV is a list of \
velocities of charges*)

Pol[n_] := {
    vmax = 1;
    amax = 1;
    sezr = Reap[
        Do[
         Sow[NaključnaTNaKrogli[]]
         , n]
        ][[2]][[1]];
    sezv = ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0}, n];
    seza = ConstantArray[{0, 0, 0}, n];
    t = 1/60;
    dt = 1/60;
    While[
     (Not[
        IntegerQ[
         t]]) \[Or] ((Max[L[sezv]] > vmax) \[And] (Max[L[seza]] > 
          amax)),
     seza = Seza[sezr, n, 100, 1, 1, sezv];
     sezv += seza dt;
     sezr += sezv dt;
     sezr /= L[sezr];
     t += dt;
     ];
    << TetGenLink`;
    {coords, incidences} = TetGenConvexHull[sezr];
    Show[
     Graphics3D[{
       EdgeForm[],
       FaceForm[Cyan],
       GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[incidences]]}],
     Background -> Black,
     Boxed -> False
     ]
    }[[1]];

(*returns graphics of polihedron with charges in end state as \
vertecies*)
Pol[78]
```

Comment: You don't need to define this `l[vektor_] := Sqrt[vektor.vektor];` yourself. Just use `Norm[vektor]`  and also `vektor/l[vektor];` just use `Normalize[vektor]`.  For the random point on the sphere, just use `RandomPoint[Sphere[{0,0,0},r]]`. You're using a strange pattern `Reap[Do[Sow...` in some places where you could just use a `Table`. You may also be interested in [`SpherePoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpherePoints.html)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119329/how-to-get-n-equidistributed-points-on-the-unit-sphere/119333#119333