# Testing visibility and projecting in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, projection

I'm trying to create a version of *Alberti's window*, a figure that represents the projection of a three-dimensional figure onto a two-dimensional plane.

Here are my steps:

1) Create the three-dimensional figure:

```
myDodecahedronFigure = 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Blue], 
   PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces", "Polygon"]}]
```

2) Extract the vertices and create a line from each to the center of projection (at {10,0,0}):

```
myVertices = N@PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Vertices"];

myProjectionLines = (Line[{{10, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ myVertices);
```

3) Put them together with the plane of projection (at x = 6):

```
Show[myDodecahedronFigure,
 Graphics3D[{Red, myProjectionLines, 
   PointSize[0.01], Point[myVertices],
   Opacity[0.5], Yellow, 
   Polygon[{{6, -2, -2}, {6, -2, 2}, {6, 2, 2}, 
            {6, 2, -2}, {6, -2, -2}}]}],
 ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

[image]

I would like to render the projections of the (red) points and the (blue) edges onto the projection plane.

**Problems**

I have two component problems:

a) I want to include only the points and edges *that are visible from the center of projection*.  (I don't want to hand-select such points.)

b) I want a natural and simple way to render lines and points on the projection plane.  (Alas `Projection` merely projects a vector onto another *vector*, so that doesn't seem of much help.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can get the lines connected to vertices visible from `vp` using the approach from [this answer by aardvark2012](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157840/125) and the intersections of those lines with the plane using `RegionIntersection`:

```
vp = {10, 0, 0};
poly = Polygon[{{6, -2, -2}, {6, -2, 2}, {6, 2, 2}, {6, 2, -2}}];

rd = RegionDifference[ConvexHullMesh[Prepend[myVertices, vp]], 
      ConvexHullMesh[myVertices]];

lines2 = Select[myProjectionLines, 
   MemberQ[Intersection[MeshCoordinates[rd], myVertices], #[[1,2]]]&];

pointsonpoly = RegionIntersection[poly, #]& /@ lines2;

Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.01], Red, Point[myVertices],
   Green, pointsonpoly,   
   Cyan,PointSize[0.02],Point@@@lines2,
   Purple, lines2, 
   Opacity[0.5], Yellow, poly,  
   myDodecahedronFigure[[1]]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: You constantly amaze me.  Who *else* knows this much about *Mathematica*??  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: Thank you @David for the kind words and the accept.

Comment: @kglr Very impressive way for a "hidden line algorithm" ! I tried your code in MMAv11.0.1 but the `RegionDifference` isn't evaluated .What could be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, thank you. I don't have access to v11. Apparently v11.2 updates to `RegionDifference`  fixed whatever was broken.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, I have to think about a major update...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, The realization of `BooleanRegion` is still strange even in V12.

Comment: @Rom38 Thanks, I have to wait til the next MMA Version ;-)