# A perforated ding dong surface

Tags: plotting

Looking at this surface, which I created with `Blender / Python`,

[image]

I asked myself how we can duplicate some aspects of the scene with `Mathematica`.

Thanks to its excellent documentation I could swiftly produce:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {Cos[u] * v Sqrt[1 - v], Sin[u] * v Sqrt[1 - v], v},
 {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Mesh -> 25,
 MeshShading -> {{Gray, Gray}, {None, Gray}},
 MeshStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

I don't think that we can produce the shadows with `Mathematica`. But would it be possible

1. to thicken the paper-thin stripes? (`Blender`'s  solidify - modifier does
   this automatically)
2. to place the Ding-Dong on a plane and add a horizon to create an illusion of depth?
3. to add some interesting lighting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easier parts of the question can be handled using `"ThickSurface"` as [`PlotTheme`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) (alternatively, using the option [`Extrusion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extrusion.html)) and [`MaterialShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaterialShading.html) as `PlotStyle`, and playing with the settings for `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh`:

```
amesh = Prepend[0] @
   Accumulate @ Riffle[ConstantArray[2 Pi/16, 16], Pi/32, {1, -1, 2}];

zmesh = Rescale[#, MinMax @ #, {-1 + 2/59, 1}] &@
  Accumulate[Flatten @ ConstantArray[{1, 5}, 10]]; 

dingdong = ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[u]*v Sqrt[1 - v], Sin[u]*v Sqrt[1 - v], v}, 
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &},
  Mesh -> {amesh, zmesh},
  PlotStyle -> MaterialShading["Iron"], 
  MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}},
  PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface",
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
  MeshStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 40 ];

shadow = ParametricPlot3D[
   {Cos[u]*v Sqrt[1 - v], Sin[u]*v Sqrt[1 - v], -1},
   {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, 
   Mesh -> {amesh, zmesh},
   PlotStyle -> LightGray, 
   MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}, 
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint", 
   MeshStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 40];

Show[dingdong, shadow]
```

[image]

Remove `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"` and add the option `Extrusion -> .1` to get

[image]

Use `MaterialShading["Gold"]` to get

[image]

Comment: And I would have bet that casting a shadow wouldn't be possible :)

Comment: `shadow` uses the quickest/dirtiest way (assuming a main light source at `{0,0 Infinity}`). Something along the lines of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203784/125) may be used to create a better shadow.