# Jeener's Flower

Tags: plotting

`Jeener's Flower` is a minimal surface attributed to the french engraver Patrice Jeener whom we can see here:

[image]

The DNA of his flower can be written as

```
rep = ReplaceAll[z :> x + I y]; 

a = rep @ Re[(z + z^5/2) * I];
b = rep @ Re[z - z^5/2];
c = rep @ Re[z^4];
```

and viewed with

```
ParametricPlot3D[{a, b, c}, {x, -1.6, 1.6}, {y, -1.6, 1.6},
 BoundaryStyle -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones",
 Mesh -> 30,
 PlotPoints -> 60,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Based upon `kglr`'s answer to my recent question:
[A perforated ding dong surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291108/a-perforated-ding-dong-surface)

I wanted to show it like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{a, b, c}, {x, -1.6, 1.6}, {y, -1.6, 1.6},
 ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones",
 Extrusion -> .5,
 Mesh -> {61, 60},
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}},
 MeshStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> {41, 41},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But I couldn't produce a closed surface - regardless of `PlotPoints` and `Mesh` settings chosen. The same problem arises with other less complicated surfaces, but not, for example, with a [Catenoid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Catenoid.html).

I don't have this problem with my `Python` version of `ParametricPlot3D` which displays in `Blender` like

[image]

The simple solution used there: Loop over all (rectangular) polygons and throw away the unwanted ones.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `MeshShading->{{Automatic,Automatic},{Automatic,None}}` seems to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specifying explicit list of mesh divisions (rather than the number of them) gives more control. The following mesh specs gives a picture close enough to the desired result:

```
meshlist = Rescale[#, MinMax @ #, {-1.6, 1.6}] & @
   Accumulate[Flatten @ ConstantArray[{1, 1/3}, 20]];

ParametricPlot3D[{a, b, c}, 
 {x, -1.6, 1.6}, {y, -1.6, 1.6}, 
 ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", 
 Extrusion -> .5, 
 Mesh -> {meshlist , Rest@ meshlist}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}, 
 MeshStyle -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> {41, 41}, 
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Replace `15` with `25` in definition of `meshlist` to get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! One additional question: Where does this `Extrusion` come from? It displays in red and I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @eldo, it is _still_ undocumented . It has worked since v10 -- perhaps earlier.  The earliest mention on this site is [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55021/125).  To avoid red highlighting, you can use it as a `Method` suboption (e.g., `Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 1, "ExtrusionStyle" -> White}`.