# Construction of a Fuller dome

Tags: plotting, graphics, generative-art

[image]

Cover of TIME magazine, January 10, 1964

Richard Buckminster Fuller (1895 - 1983) was an American architect and designer. He popularized the [Geodesic Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome). Carbon molecules are also known as [Fullerenes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fullerene.html) for their mathematical resemblance to geodesic spheres.

[image]

Buckminster Fuller (Mid) and [Josef Albers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Albers) (left) with students at Black Mountain College, summer 1948: Construction of a geodesic dome.

We can visualize geodesic structures with `PolyhedronData` or, as Syed commented, with `GeodesicPolyhedron`:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "Skeleton", "Rule"] // GraphPlot3D,
  PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "Faces", "Graphics3D"],
  PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "Edges", "Graphics3D"] /.
   Line -> ({MaterialShading["Iron"], Tube[#, 0.1]} &)}]
```

[image]

`GraphPlot3d` looks like one of Fullers creations:

[image]

**Question 1:**

Can we produce a structure with steel bands instead of tubes (like in the 2nd photo from above)? With other words: Can we cut out the polygon faces similar to kglr's answer of this question: [Jeeners Flower](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291201/jeeners-flower) ?

[image]

**Question 2**

Can we combine faces and tubified edges similar to this structure, which I produced by exporting faces and edges of the `PentagonalHexecontahedron` to `Blender` ?

[image]

Comment: For reference: the [GeodesicPolyhedron](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeodesicPolyhedron.html) doc page.

Comment: Thanks, Syed, very interesting, I didn't know that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** For Q1:

```
ClearAll[thickenPolygonEdges]

thickenPolygonEdges[width_ : .3, thickness_ : .05][bmesh_] := 
 MeshPrimitives[bmesh, 2] /. 
  Polygon[x_] :> 
   Module[{c = Mean@x, p1 = Partition[x, 2, 1, {1, 1}], p2}, 
    p2 = Map[Reverse]@
      Partition[Map[(c + (1 - width) (# - c)) &, x], 2, 1, {1, 1}]; 
    ReplaceAll[Polygon[y_] :> 
       ConvexHullMesh[Join[y, (1 + thickness) y]]]@
     MapThread[Polygon@*Join]@{p1, p2}]


bmr = PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];

RegionUnion @@ Flatten[thickenPolygonEdges[] @ bmr]
```

[image]

```
inradius = PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "Inradius"];


Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], MaterialShading["Iron"], 
   thickenPolygonEdges[] @ bmr}, Lighting -> "ThreePoint", 
  Boxed -> False,  ImageSize -> Large], 
 Graphics3D[{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Darker@Green}], 
   Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.05 inradius]}]]
```

[image]

Replace `Sphere[...]` with `MeshPrimitives[bmr, 2]` to get

[image]

Not sure if the following is needed but could be useful to play with:

```
ClearAll[subdivideFaces]

subdivideFaces[centerheight_ : 1.05][bmesh_] := 
 Module[{mc = MeshCoordinates@bmesh,
   mcc = centerheight AnnotationValue[{bmesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid], 
   faceindices = MeshCells[bmesh, 2][[All, 1]]}, 
  BoundaryMeshRegion[Join[mc, mcc], 
   MapIndexed[
     Map[Polygon]@
       Map[Append[Length[mc] + #2[[1]]]]@
        Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, 1}] &] @ faceindices]]


subdivideFaces[][bmr]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Gray}], 
   thickenPolygonEdges[]@subdivideFaces[][bmr]}, 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Large], 
 Graphics3D[{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Darker@Green}], 
   Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.05 inradius]}]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

For Q2:

```
bmr = PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];


MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates@bmr,  
 MeshCells[bmr, 1 | 2], 
 MeshCellShapeFunction -> 
   {1 -> ({MaterialShading["Iron"], Tube[#, .15]} &), 
    2 -> ({MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Darker@Green}], Polygon@#} &)}, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint"]
```

[image]

```
inradius = PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "Inradius"];

Show[MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates@bmr,  
    MeshCells[bmr, 1], 
    MeshCellShapeFunction -> {1 -> ({MaterialShading["Iron"], Tube[#, .15]} &)},
    Lighting -> "ThreePoint"], 
 Graphics3D[{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Darker @ Green}], 
   Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.05 inradius]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , certainly much more than I hoped for. Maybe you should change the definition sequence: The second image from above only shows after evaluating `thickenPolygonEdges` and `inradius`. Could be confusing for an occasional user.

Answer (score 7):

Just an idea for **Question 2**:

```
chm = ConvexHullMesh@Point[PolyhedronData["PentagonalHexecontahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]];

Show[
    Graphics3D[{ MaterialShading["Foil"], Sphere[]}
      , Lighting -> {"ThreePoint"}, Boxed -> False]
  , Graphics3D[{MaterialShading["Iron"]
     , MeshPrimitives[chm, 1] /. 
       Line[{a_, b_}] :> Tube[Table[Normalize[t a + (1 - t) b], {t, 0, 1, 1/50}], .025]}]
  , ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Update for **Question 1** (still with tubes instead of steel bands)

```
bdr = BoundaryMeshRegion[GeodesicPolyhedron["Icosahedron", 3]];
pts = Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[bdr, 0];
lines = Sequence @@@ MeshPrimitives[bdr, 1];
centroids = Select[pts, Length@Counts[Round[#, .01] & /@ 
   EuclideanDistance @@@ Cases[lines, l_ /; ContainsAny[l, {#}]]] == 1 &];
nearest[centroid_] := Line[{centroid, #}] & /@ NearestTo[centroid, 7][centroids]

Show[
   Graphics3D[{LightGreen, Opacity[.7], Sphere[]}, 
     Lighting -> {"Accent"}, Boxed -> False]
 , Graphics3D[{Directive[LightGray]
   , MeshPrimitives[bdr, 1] /. Line[{a_, b_}] :> 
     Tube[Table[Normalize[t a + (1 - t) b], {t, 0, 1, 1/50}], .020]
   }]
 , Graphics3D[{Directive[LightGray]
   , (nearest /@ centroids) /. Line[{a_, b_}] :> 
     Tube[Table[Normalize[t a + (1 - t) b], {t, 0, 1, 1/50}], .018]
   }], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, vindobona, an excellent solution!

Comment: @eldo You're welcome! :-)