# How to build a spherical polygon on a sphere?

Tags: graphics3d

How to build a spherical polygon on a sphere.moreover. Manually changing the number of sides of the polygon?

Comment: Have a look at [SphericalPolygon](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SphericalPolygon/)

Comment: The post could use some good cleanup, but I don't find this question as bad as other uses who voted for closing it. It is not like `SphericalPolygon` were part of the language. @Eldo Your comment is awesome; please change it into an answer. I think in this case a 1-link answer is justified.

Comment: Related [Construction of a Fuller Dome](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292697/construction-of-a-fuller-dome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested I turn my comment into an answer:

```
SP = ResourceFunction["SphericalPolygon"] (* Author: Jan Mangaldan *);
```

Example from its [documentation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SphericalPolygon/) (with minor changes)

```
coord =
  First /@ First[Normal[MapAt[Map[Normalize, #] &,
      N[PolyhedronData["TruncatedIcosahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]], 1]]];

Graphics3D[Map[{GrayLevel[If[Length[#] == 5, 0, 0.8]],
    SP[#, "EdgeStyle" -> GrayLevel[0.4], "ShowEdges" -> True]} &, coord],
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
coord =
  First /@ First[Normal[MapAt[Map[Normalize, #] &,
      N[PolyhedronData["DisdyakisTriacontahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]], 1]]];

Graphics3D[Map[
   {RGBColor[0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5],
     SP[#, "EdgeStyle" -> GrayLevel[0.8], "ShowEdges" -> True]} &, coord],
  Boxed -> False,
  Lighting -> "Neutral"] /. Line :> (Tube[#, 0.015] &)
```

[image]

Related

[construction-of-a-fuller-dome](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292697/construction-of-a-fuller-dome)