# Replicating Sol LeWitt's skeletal geometries

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, generative-art, polygons, polyhedra

Sol LeWitt (1928 - 2007) was an American artist linked to various movements, including conceptual art and minimalism. He used lines, geometric solids, patterns, formulas and permutations to create his structures and wall paintings. Most of his works have a decidedly mathematical flavour. LeWitt's works are found in the most important museum collections worldwide.

[image]

For the art piece I want to reproduce with Mathematica, LeWitt was probably inspired by Leonardo da Vinci's illustrations for Luca Pacioli's 1509 book *The Divine Proportion*.

[image]

Images from the [Mathematical Association of America](https://maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/leonardo-da-vincis-geometric-sketches-icosahedron)

It is relatively easy to reproduce skeletal polyhedra if we use tubes:

```
Graphics3D[{MaterialShading["Bronze"], PolyhedronData[#, "Lines"]},
     Boxed -> False,
     ImageSize -> 200,
     Lighting -> "ThreePoint"] /.
    Line :> (Tube[#, 0.04] &) & /@ {{"Pyramid", 4}, "Cube", "Dodecahedron"} // Row
```

[image]

But it is much more difficult to replicate Leonardo's style with rectangular polygons. Fortunately, kglr showed how we can do it in his answer to this question:

[Construction of a Fuller dome](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292697/construction-of-a-fuller-dome)

```
Perforate[width_ : .3, thickness_ : .05][bmesh_] := 
 MeshPrimitives[bmesh, 2] /. 
  Polygon[x_] :> 
   Module[{c = Mean @ x, p1 = Partition[x, 2, 1, {1, 1}], p2}, 
    p2 = Map[Reverse] @ Partition[Map[(c + (1 - width) (# - c)) &, x], 2, 1, {1, 1}];
    ReplaceAll[Polygon[y_] :> ConvexHullMesh[Join[y, (1 + thickness) y]]] @
      MapThread[Polygon @* Join] @ {p1, p2}]

Graphics3D[
 Perforate[0.2] @ PolyhedronData["GreatRhombicosidodecahedron", "BoundaryMeshRegion"],
  Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

As Syed commented, there is also a repository function which might be useful: [OutlinePolygons](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OutlinePolygons/)

Using this technique I started with my replica of LeWitt's *Five Open Geometric Structures (1979)*:

[image]

The cube looked promising,

```
Graphics3D[{
  MaterialShading[<|"BaseColor" -> White, "MetallicCoefficient" -> 1, "RoughnessCoefficient" -> 0.5|>],
  Perforate[.2] @ PolyhedronData["Cube", "BoundaryMeshRegion"]},
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.4],
 Lighting -> {"Standard", GrayLevel[0.9]},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Thanks to kglr's comment I could also produce the 4-sided pyramid:

```
center =
 TransformedRegion[#,TranslationTransform[RegionCentroid[#]]] &;

Graphics3D[{
  MaterialShading[<|"BaseColor" -> White, "MetallicCoefficient" -> 1, "RoughnessCoefficient" -> 0.5|>], 
  Perforate[.2] @ center @ PolyhedronData[{"Pyramid", 4}, "BoundaryMeshRegion"]}, 
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.4], 
 Lighting -> {"Standard", GrayLevel[0.9]},
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

But the cuboid failed miserably producing lots of "ConvexHullMesh" error messages. The evildoer:

```
Graphics3D[Perforate[.2] @ BoundaryMeshRegion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}]]];
```

**My Question**

How can we reproduce the *Five Open Geometric Structures*?

If it is too difficult to find a polygon-based solution, I would also accept tubes or even solids, if they are neatly placed next to each other on a board with the right `ViewPoint` and `ViewAngle`.

**Addendum**

More Sol LeWitt on this tour of the Lisson Gallery:

[Lisson Gallery](https://www.lissongallery.com/artists/sol-lewitt)

[image]

Comment: Useful link: [OutlinePolygons](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OutlinePolygons/).

Comment: Thank you, Syed, I will add the link to my question

Comment: for a (partial) rehabilitation of `Perforate`, pre-process input mesh with `centerAtOrigin = 
  TransformedRegion[#, TranslationTransform[RegionCentroid[#]]] &`?

Comment: Thank you, kglr, with your addition I can now produce the 4-sided pyramid. Also the cuboid, but with some mistakes. The repository function suggested by Syed also perforates the cuboid, but with even more mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that if we replace `ConvexHullMesh` to `ConvexHullRegion` in the excellent code of @kglr, all of the thing is OK now.

```
Clear[Perforate];
Perforate[width_ : .3, thickness_ : .05][bmesh_] := 
 MeshPrimitives[bmesh, 2] /. 
  Polygon[x_] :> 
   Module[{c = Mean@x, p1 = Partition[x, 2, 1, {1, 1}], p2}, 
    p2 = Map[Reverse]@
      Partition[Map[(c + (1 - width)  (# - c)) &, x], 2, 1, {1, 1}];
    ReplaceAll[
      Polygon[y_] :> ConvexHullRegion[Join[y, (1 + thickness)  y]]]@
     MapThread[Polygon@*Join]@{p1, p2}]
```

- We also test the example from https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OutlinePolygons/

```
{reg1, reg2, reg3, 
   reg4} = {PolyhedronData[{"Pyramid", 4}, "BoundaryMeshRegion"], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}], Cube[], 
   DiscretizeGraphics[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Beethoven"}]]};

Graphics3D[{MaterialShading[<|"BaseColor" -> White, 
      "MetallicCoefficient" -> 1, "RoughnessCoefficient" -> 0.5|>], 
    Perforate[.2]@#}, Background -> GrayLevel[0.4], 
   Lighting -> {"Standard", GrayLevel[0.9]}, 
   Boxed -> False] & /@ {reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4}
```

[image]