# How can we dice a parametric surface? - Part II

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, generative-art

A few days ago I asked:

[How can we dice a parametric surface?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297324/how-can-we-dice-a-parametric-surface)

Now I have two follow-up questions concerning the elegant answer given by kglr.

He handles the dicing with three short functions:

```
roundCoordinates[r_ : .2] :=
  ReplaceAll[
   GraphicsComplex[c_, p___] :> GraphicsComplex[Round[c, r], p]];

polygonToCuboid =
  ReplaceAll[Polygon[x_, ___, VertexColors -> vc_, ___] :>
    {RGBColor @ Mean[vc], Cuboid @@ Transpose[CoordinateBounds @ x]}];

displayFunction[r_ : .2] :=
  polygonToCuboid @* Normal @* roundCoordinates[r];
```

Example

```
opts = {
   Axes -> False,
   Boxed -> False,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   Lighting -> "Neutral",
   Mesh -> All,
   SphericalRegion -> True};

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sqrt[1 - v] v, Sin[u] Sqrt[1 - v] v, v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1},
 Evaluate @ opts,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedBlueTones"][#3] &),
 DisplayFunction -> displayFunction[0.2],
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 PlotPoints -> 17]
```

[image]

**Question 1**

At the bottom as well as below and above the upper part there are some "sheets" which were skipped by the dicing operation. Would it be possible to either dice them too or, preferably, extrude them a little bit?

**Question 2**

If I want to use `PlotStyle` instead of `ColorFunction`, I must change the definition of `polygonToCuboid`. Example:

```
polygonToCuboid =
  ReplaceAll[Polygon[x_, ___] :> {Cuboid @@ Transpose[CoordinateBounds @ x]}];

ParametricPlot3D[
 {Sin[u ], v, 0.5 Sin[2 u]}, {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, -0.1, 0.1},
 Evaluate @ opts,
 DisplayFunction -> displayFunction[0.05],
 MaxRecursion -> 1,
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 PlotStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]

It would be nice if `polygonToCuboid` could handle both cases (mono, color) automatically.

Comment: For Q2, use `polygonToCuboid =  ReplaceAll[ Polygon[x_,  opts___] :> {Cases[{opts},   HoldPattern[VertexColors -> vc_] :> RGBColor@Mean[vc], All],  Cuboid @@ Transpose[CoordinateBounds@x]}];`