# How can we color perforated polyhedra?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, color, polyhedra

**1. Color a polyhedron**

It is relatively easy to color a polyhedron using its polygon edge counts as color directive:

Color according to edge count

```
$color = 
  <|{3 -> Red, 4 -> Orange, 5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Darker @ Green, 8 -> Blue, 10 -> Purple}|>;
```

Define `ColorPolygon`

```
ColorPolygon[GraphicsComplex[v_, Polygon[poly_]]] := 
 GraphicsComplex[v, ({Glow @ $color[Length @ First @ #], Polygon @ #} &) /@ 
   SplitBy[Sort @ poly, Length]]
```

Example polyhedron

```
$poly = "GreatRhombicosidodecahedron";
```

Show it

```
Graphics3D[
 ColorPolygon[PolyhedronData[$poly, "GraphicsComplex"]],
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> None]
```

[image]

**2. Perforate a polyhedron**

In his answer to [Construction of a Fuller dome](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292697/construction-of-a-fuller-dome) kglr showed how to perforate a polyhedron:

```
PerforatePolygon[width_ : 0.3, thickness_ : .05][bmesh_] := 
 MeshPrimitives[bmesh, 2] /. 
  Polygon[x_] :> Module[{c = Mean @ x, p1, p2},
    p1 = Partition[x, 2, 1, {1, 1}];
    p2 = Map[Reverse] @ Partition[Map[(c + (1 - width) (# - c)) &, x], 2, 1, {1, 1}];
    ReplaceAll[Polygon[y_] :> ConvexHullMesh[Join[y, (1 + thickness) y]]] @
     MapThread[Polygon @* Join] @ {p1, p2}]
```

Perforate `$poly`

```
Graphics3D[
 PerforatePolygon[0.2] @ PolyhedronData[$poly, "BoundaryMeshRegion"],
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**3. My question**

I would like to use both, color and perforation, to highlight the structure of a polyhedron. Obviously, we cannot use the edge count (all polygons have 4) to color a perforated polygon, but are there alternate methods?

Here is a randomly found and over-simplified example of what I have in mind:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ClearAll[colorAndPerforatePolygon]
colorAndPerforatePolygon[width_ : 0.3, thickness_ : .05][bmesh_, colorrules_] := 
 KeyValueMap[{# /. colorrules, #2} &]@
   GroupBy[MeshPrimitives[bmesh, 2], Length@*First] /. 
  Polygon[x_] :> 
   Module[{c = Mean@x, p1, p2}, p1 = Partition[x, 2, 1, {1, 1}];
    p2 = Map[Reverse]@
      Partition[
       Map[If[Head[width] === Scaled, 
         # - First[width ] (# - c), 
         # - width Normalize[# - c]] &, x], 
       2, 1, {1, 1}];
    ReplaceAll[Polygon[y_] :> ConvexHullMesh[Join[y, (1 + thickness) y]]]@
     MapThread[Polygon@*Join]@{p1, p2}]
```

***Examples:***

```
$color = <|{3 -> Red, 4 -> Orange, 5 -> Yellow, 6 -> Darker@Green, 
    8 -> Blue, 10 -> Purple}|>;

Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
  colorAndPerforatePolygon[0.2][
     PolyhedronData[$poly, "BoundaryMeshRegion"], $color]},
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
  colorAndPerforatePolygon[Scaled @ 0.2][
     PolyhedronData[$poly, "BoundaryMeshRegion"], $color]},
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, kglr, thank you so much

Comment: @eldo, you are most welcome.