# 3D representation of a Boy surface using a mesh of tubes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

*“Everything that matters in life flows through tubes.”* - Georg Christoph Lichtenberg, The Waste Books

[image: Model of a Boy surface at the Mathematical Research Institute of Oberwolfach, Germany]

Model of a Boy surface at the `Mathematical Research Institute of Oberwolfach`, Germany

**1. Preceding questions**

This is (hopefully) the last of three questions concerning display options of `ParametricPlot3D`. The first two are

[A perforated ding dong surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291108/a-perforated-ding-dong-surface)

and

[Jeener's Flower](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291201/jeeners-flower)

**2. Parametrization**

```
x = 1/2 * ((2 * a^2 - b^2 - c^2) + 2 * b * c * (b^2 - c^2) + c * a * (a^2 - c^2) + a * b * (b^2 - a^2));
y = 7/8 * ((b^2 - c^2) + c * a * (c^2 - a^2) + a * b * (b^2 - a^2));
z = -1/8 * (a + b + c) * ((a + b + c)^3 + 4 * (b - a) * (c - b) * (a - c));

boy = {x, y, z} /. {a :> Sin[u] * Sin[v], b :> Cos[u] * Sin[v], c :> Cos[v]};
```

**3. ParametricPlot3D**

The appearance of a Boy surface changes significantly with different viewpoints.

```
Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[boy, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
   Axes -> False,
   Boxed -> False,
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
   PlotPoints -> 40,
   PlotStyle -> MaterialShading["Iron"],
   ViewPoint -> v],
  {v, {Top, Below, {1.3, -2.4, 2}}}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: three points of view in 3D space]

**4. Tubification**

To look inside and through the surface I tried:

```
ParametricPlot3D[boy, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
  Axes -> False,
  Mesh -> 12,
  PlotPoints -> 80,
  PlotStyle -> None,
  ViewPoint -> Above] /. Line :> ({Darker @ Red, Tube[#, 0.02]} &)
```

[image: surface representation using a mesh of tubes]

And to see the first two "generating" curves:

```
ParametricPlot3D[boy, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
  Axes -> False,
  Mesh -> 1,
  PlotPoints -> 40,
  PlotStyle -> None,
  ViewPoint -> Top] /. Line :> ({Darker @ Red, Tube[#, 0.02]} &)
```

[image: tube representation of two generating surfaces]

**5. Questions** (sorted by relevance)

1. With my very basic appended tubification method I cannot colorize the tubes, nor can I apply a material to them.
2. The first tube plot has a very flat appearance. Maybe an appropriate lighting or another view angle would give a nicer result.
3. I would like to have an option to change the tube profile from round to rectangular.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D[boy, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> 1, PlotStyle -> None, ViewPoint -> Above, 
 MeshStyle -> {{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Tube[0.07]}}]`?

Comment: Very very nice - please post this as an answer

Comment: Hi @eldo, these are great!  If you're interested I have a parameterization for Girl's surface that I can share if you want to do that to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** Using one-parameter `ParametricPlot3D`

```
{umesh, vmesh} = {Pi/2, Pi/2};

{boy1, boy2} = boy /. {{u -> umesh}, {v -> vmesh, u -> v}}; 

ParametricPlot3D[{boy1, boy2}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
     {Tube[.1], 
      {MaterialShading["Iron"], Tube[.1]}}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
  ViewPoint -> Top, 
  Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[boy /. u -> i, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/30}]], 
 {v, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{MaterialShading["Gold"], Tube[.02]}}, 
 PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> All,  
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[boy /. v -> i, {i, 0, Pi, Pi/30}]], 
 {u, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Tube[.02],
 ColorFunction -> (Hue @ #4 &),
 PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> All,  
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Axes -> False]
```

[image]

---

### 1. Colorize tubes and apply `MaterialShading`:

#### Post-processing

```
ParametricPlot3D[boy, 
   {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
   Axes -> False, 
   Mesh -> 1, 
   PlotPoints -> 40, 
   PlotStyle -> None, 
   ViewPoint -> Top] /. 
 Line -> ({MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Tube[#, 0.07]} &)
```

[image]

Replace `MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}]` with `MaterialShading["Iron"]` to get

[image]

Use the rule

```
Line -> 
 ({Tube[#, 0.07, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Subdivide[Length@#])]} &)
```

to get

[image]

#### MeshStyle with Tube as directive

Alternatively, you can use `{directives, Tube[radius]}` as a directive in `MeshStyle`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[boy, 
  {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, Pi},
  Axes -> False,  
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotStyle -> None, 
  ViewPoint -> Above,  
  Mesh -> 1, 
  MeshStyle -> {{MaterialShading[{"Glazed", Red}], Tube[0.07]}}]
```

[image]

Use `MaterialShading["Iron"]` to get

[image]

Use options `ColorFunction -> Hue` and `MeshStyle -> {{Tube[0.07]}}` to get

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to apply a `ColorFunction` and/or `MaterialShading["Iron"]`?

Comment: @eldo, added some examples. I don't know how to apply `ColorFunction` _**and**_ `MaterialShading`.

Comment: I didn' want to use them together. The important thing is that I now can combine `ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors"` with `MeshStyle -> Tube[0.02]`.  When was `MeshStyle -> Tube[...]` introduced?  Couldn't find it in the docs.

Comment: `Tube[radius]` as directive in `PlotStyle` or in `MeshStyle` is undocumented. I think I learned about it from [this answer by John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5972/125) or/and from [this answer by Yu-Sung Chang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3925/125)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my code for the Bryant-Kunser parametrization of the Boy surface.

```
g[w_] := {-3/2 Im[w (1 - w^4)/(w^6 + Sqrt[5] w^3 - 1)],
          -3/2 Re[w (1 + w^4)/(w^6 + Sqrt[5] w^3 - 1)],
          Im[(1 + w^6)/(w^6 + Sqrt[5] w^3 - 1)] - 1/2};

b[u_, v_] := #/(#.#) &[g[v Exp[I u]]];
```

Interactive plot of the curves of constant $v$, with colored tubes:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[b[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-2, 1}},
     Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True,
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm[None], JoinForm["Miter"]], 
     ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors", Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}] /. 
     Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.025, rest],
     {v, 0, 1}]
```

Interactive plot of the closed curves along $u$ and $u + \pi$:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{b[u, v], b[u + Pi, v]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-2, 1}},
     Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True,
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm[None], JoinForm["Miter"]], 
     ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors", Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}] /. 
     Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.025, rest],
     {u, 0, Pi}]
```

Combined plots:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[b[u, v], {v, 0, 1, .025}]], {u, 0, 2 Pi},
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-2, 1}},
     Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True,
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm[None], JoinForm["Miter"]], 
     ColorFunction -> "AlpineColors", Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}] /. 
     Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.025, rest]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Table[b[u, v], {u, Pi/40, 2 Pi, Pi/40}]], {v, 0, 1},
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-2, 1}},
     Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, Axes -> True,
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[CapForm[None], JoinForm["Miter"]], 
     ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}] /.
     Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.025, rest]
```

[image]
[image]

The code I've used has been adapted from the documentation of `Tube`, under Neat Examples; in particular, the options `PlotStyle` and `Method` for `ParametricPlot3D`, and the replacement of `Line` with `Tube`.

Comment: Impressive, thank you :)